# Seeing Facebook page through a test user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I want to integrate a Facebook page to ServiceNow.

I created a page with my personal account and an app on developers.facebook.com to extend my access token for 60 days. I made the REST connection successfully and was able to pull the posts and comments on that page into the database of the ServiceNow table.

Subsequently, my profile was blocked for a couple of days and I was informed the app that I made was violating certain Facebook policies. But after submitting the ID, it got reactivated. Then I made some test users so that I could comment on any post of that page to check if that comes into the ITSM database.

However, when I login through a test user, I cannot see the Facebook page associated with my personal Facebook profile.

*I need to know how can I see posts of my page through a test user and comment on them. Do I need to provide any specific role to the test user for the same?*

Comment: Test users can not interact with real pages; you would have to use pages created by the test user.

Comment: @CBroe An app can't be linked to a test page, and a test user can't use a real page (even when the page is in developing mode), but only real pages can be linked to apps. It's a catch 22 situation, or am I missing something?